# What is the difference between fallback false vs true vs blocking of getStaticPaths with and without revalidate in Next.js SSR/ISR?

Tags: next.js

As of Next.js 10, the `getStaticPaths` function returns an object that must contain the very important `fallback` key as documented at: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required

While the documentation is precise, it is quite hard to digest for someone that is just beginning with Next.js, could someone try to provide a simpler or more concrete overview of those options?

Answer (score 116):

## **How to test**

First of all, when testing things out to make sure I had understood them, I was getting really confused because when you run in development mode (`next dev`) the behavior is quite different than when running in production mode (`next build && next start`), as it is much more forgiving to help you develop quickly. Notably, in development, [`getStaticPaths` gets called on every render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61037728/next-js-getstaticprops-and-getstaticpaths-with-dynamic-routes-to-generate-stati/61039377#61039377) , so everything always gets rendered to their latest version, which is unlike production where more caching might be enabled.

The docs describe the production behavior, so to test things out, you really need to use production mode.

The next issue is that I couldn't easily find an example where you can create and update pages from inside the example itself to easily view their behavior. I finally ended up doing that at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/node-express-sequelize-nextjs-realworld-example-app while porting the awesome [Realworld example](https://github.com/gothinkster/realworld) project, which produces a simple multiuser blog website (mini Medium clone).

With those tools in hand, I was able to confirm what the docs say. This answer was tested [at this commit](https://github.com/cirosantilli/node-express-sequelize-nextjs-realworld-example-app/tree/7def72741eb4123deed9b5e956967d5ca6ba2f6e) which has Next.js 10.2.2.

## **`fallback: false`**

This one is simple: only pages that are generated during `next build` (i.e. returned from the `paths` property of `getStaticPaths`) will be visible.

E.g., if a user creates a new blog page at `/post/[post-id]`, it will not be immediately visible afterwards, and visiting that URL will lead to a 404.

That new post will only become visible if you re-run `next build`, and `getStaticPaths` returns that page under `paths`, which is the case for the typical use case where `getStaticPaths` returns all the possible `[post-id]`.

## **`fallback: true`**

With this option, Next checks if the page has been pre-rendered to HTML under `.next/server/pages`.

If it has not:

1. Next first quickly returns a dummy pre-render with empty data that had been created at build time.

   In this, you are expected to tell the user that the page is loading.

   You must handle that case, or else it could lead to exceptions being thrown due to missing properties.

   The way to handle this is described in the docs by checking `router.isFallback`:

   ```
   import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

   function Post({ post }) {
       const router = useRouter()

       // If the page is not yet generated, this will be displayed
       // initially until getStaticProps() finishes running
       if (router.isFallback) {
           return <div>Loading...</div>
       }

       // Render post...
       return <div>{post.body}</div>

   }
   ```

   So in this example, if we hadn't done the `router.isFallback` check, post would be `{}`, and doing `post.body` would throw an exception
2. After the actual page finishes rendering for the first time with data (the data is fetched with `getStaticProps` at runtime), the user's browser gets automatically updated to see it, and it stores the resulting HTML under `.next/server/pages`

If the page is present under `.next/server/pages` however, either because:

- it was rendered by `next build`
- it was rendered for the first time at runtime

Next.js just returns it, without rendering again.

Therefore, If you edit the post, **it will not re-render the page cache**. The outdated page will be returned at all times, because it is already present under `.next/server/pages`, so next does not re-render it.

You will have to re-run `next build` to see updated versions of the pages.

Therefore, this is not what you generally want for the multi-user blog described above. This approach is generally only suitable for websites that don't have user-generated content, e.g. an e-commerce website where you control all the content.

### **`fallback: true`: what about pages that don't exist?**

If the user accesses a page that does not exist like `/post/i-dont-exist`, Next.js will try to render it just like any other page, because it checks that it is not in `.next/server/pages` thinks that it just hasn't been rendered before.

This is unlike `fallback: false`, where Next.js never generates new pages at runtime, and just returns a 404 direction.

In this case, your code will notice that the page does not exist when `getStaticProps` queries the database, and then you tell Next.js that this is a 404 with `notFound: true` as mentioned at: [How to return a 404 Not Found page and HTTP status when an invalid parameter of a dynamic route is passed in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67773885/how-to-return-a-404-not-found-page-and-http-status-when-an-invalid-parameter-of/67773886#67773886) so Next.js renders a 404 page and caches nothing.

## **`fallback: 'blocking'`**

This is quite similar to `fallback: true`, except that it does not return the dummy loading page when a page that hasn't been cached is hit for the first time

Instead, it just makes the browser hang, until the page is rendered for the first time.

Future requests to that page are quickly served from the cache however, just like `fallback: true`.

https://dev.to/tomdohnal/blocking-fallback-for-getstaticpaths-new-next-js-10-feature-1727 mentions the rationale for this, it appears to break certain rather specific features, and is generally not what you want unless you need one of those specific features.

Note that Next.js documentation explicitly states that in `fallback: true`, it detects crawlers (TODO how exactly? User agent or something else? Which user agents), and does not return the loading page to crawlers, which would defeat the purpose of SSR. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-fallback-key-required mentions:

> Note: this "fallback" version will not be served for crawlers like Google and instead will render the path in blocking mode.

so there doesn't seem to be a huge advantage for SEO purposes in using `'blocking'` over `true`.

However, if your user is a security freak and disables JavaScript, they will only see the loading page. And are you sure the Wayback machine won't show the loading page? What about `wget`? Since I like such use cases, I'm tempted to just use `fallback: 'blocking'` everywhere.

## **`revalidate`: Incremental Static Regeneration (ISR)**

When `revalidate` is given, new requests to a page that is in the `.next/server/pages` cache also make the cache be regenerated. This is called "Incremental Static Regeneration".

`revalidate: n` means that our server will do at most 1 re-render every `n` seconds. If a second request comes in before the `n` seconds, the previously rendered page is returned and a new re-render is not triggered. So large `n` means users see more outdated pages, but less server workload.

A large re validate could therefore help the server handle large traffic peaks by caching the reply.

This is what we have to use if we want website users to both publish and update their own posts:

- either `fallback: true` or `fallback: 'blocking'`
- together with `revalidate: <integer>`

`revalidate` does not make much sense with `fallback: false`.

When `revalidate: <number>` is given, behavior is as follows:

- if the page is present under `.next/server/pages`, return this prerendered immediately, possibly rendered with outdated data.

  At the same, also kickstart a page rebuild with the newest data.

  When the rebuild is finished, the target page won't be automatically updated to the latest version. The user would have to refresh the page to see the updated version.
- otherwise, if the page is not cached, do the same that `true` or `'blocking'` would do, by either returning a dummy wait page, or blocking until it gets done, and create the cached page

After a page is built by either of the above cases (first time or not), if it gets accessed again in the next `number` seconds, do not trigger rebuilds. This way, if a very large number of users is visiting the website, most of the requests won't require expensive server render work: we will do at most one re-render every `number` seconds.

### **Explicit invalidation with: `res.unstable_revalidate`**

This is currently beta, but it seems that at last they are introducing a way to explicitly invalidate pages as currently mentioned at: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration

This way, instead of ugly `revalidate` timeouts, we will be able to just rebuild pages only when needed if we are able to detect the page becoming outdated on the server. Then we can just sever directly every time.

It will presumably be renamed to `res.revalidate` once it becomes stable.

This awesome development was brought to my attention by [Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746804/sebastian) in the comments.

**SSR for a single request (i.e. ignore `revalidate`) so that users can see the results of their blog page edits**

Edit: this use case might best resolved with the upcoming `res.unstable_revalidate`/`res.revalidate`.

If for example:

- the blog author clicks submit after updating an existing post
- and they got redirected to the post view page as is usual behavior, to see if everything looks OK

they first see the outdated version of the post. Then redirected this visit would trigger a rebuilt with the new data they've provided in the edit page, and only after that finishes and the user refreshes they would see the updated page.

So this behavior is also not ideal UI behavior for the editor, as the user would be left thinking:

> What just happened, was my edit not registered?

for a few seconds.

This can be solved with "preview mode" which is documented at: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/preview-mode It was added in Next.js 12. Preview mode checks if come cookies are set, and if so makes `getStaticProps` rerun regardless of `revalidate`, just like `getServerSideProps`.

However, even preview mode does not solve this use case super nicely, because it does not invalidate/update the cache, which is a widely requested thing, related:

- [Next.js ISR ( Incremental Static Regeneration ), how to rebuild or update a specific page manually or dynamically before the interval/ISR time start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062987/next-js-isr-incremental-static-regeneration-how-to-rebuild-or-update-a-spec)
- [How to clear/delete cache in NextJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444505/how-to-clear-delete-cache-in-nextjs)

so it could still happen that the user visits the page without cache and sees the outdated page. I could work around this by removing the cookies and making a an extra GET request, but this produces an useless get request and adds more complexity.

I learned about this after opening an issue about it at: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/25677 thanks to [@sergioengineer](https://github.com/sergioengineer) for pointing it out.

Related threads:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11698#discussioncomment-351289
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11552

### **SSR vs ISR: per user-login-based information**

ISR is an optimization over SSR. However, like every optimization, it can increase the complexity of the system.

For example, suppose that users can "favorite" blog posts.

If we use ISR, it only makes much sense to pre-render a logged off page, because it only makes sense to pre-render the stuff that is common for multiple users.

Therefore, if we want to show to the user the information:

> Have I starred this page yet or not?

then we have to do a second API request and then update the page state with it.

While it may sound simple, this adds considerable extra complexity to the code in my experience.

With SSR however, we could simply check the login cookies sent by the user as usual, and fully render the page perfectly customized to the current user on the server, so that no further API requests will be needed. Much simpler.

So you should really only do it if you benchmark it and it is worth it.

Here's an example of checking login cookies: https://github.com/cirosantilli/node-express-sequelize-nextjs-realworld-example-app/blob/8dff36e4bcf659fd048e13f246d50c776fff0028/back/IndexPage.ts#L23 That sample setup uses the exact same SWR tokens that are being used to make JavaScript API requests but also via cookies. We don't have to worry about XSS in that demo because we only use login on GET requests. All modifying requests like POST are done from JavaScript exclusively, and don't authenticate from cookies.

### **The ISR dream: infinite `revalidate` + explicit invalidation + CDN  hooks**

As of Next.js 12, ISR is wonky for such a CRUD website, what I would really want is for things to work as follows:

- when the user creates a blog post, we use a post creation hook to upload the result to a CDN of choice
- when a user views a blog post, it goes to the CDN directly and does not touch the server. Only if the user wants to fetch user-specific data such as "have I starred this page" does it make a small API request to the server
- when a user updates a blog post, it just updates the result on the CDN of choice

This approach would really lead to ultra-fast page loads and minimal server workload Nirvana.

I think Vercel, the company behind Next.js, might such a CDN system running on their product, but I don't see how to nicely use an arbitrary CDN of choice, because I don't see such hooks. I hope I'm wrong :-)

But just the explicit invalidation + infinite revalidate would already be a great thing to have even without the CDN hook system. Edit: this might be coming with `res.unstable_revalidate`, see section above.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't know that one major rationale for the existence of `blocking` is for search engines not to cache the "loading" state.

Comment: Next.js just introduced On-Demand Revalidation. It allows you to actively trigger the update of a page. For example if content was changed at your backend. Please see at the middle of this page to learn more https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/next.js/incremental-static-regeneration - super cool feature since YOU decide and know best when a page needs to be updated.

Comment: @Sebastian fantastic news! Something I really want. Mentioned in answer now.

Comment: great, thank you that you updated your answer to so quickly. Your text is so good, maybe you want to publish it at your blog or so, too? Super helpful overview 

Comment: @Sebastian Stack Overflow is my blog! It is hard to have higher pagerank than it. I only split on the rare cases that I reach the 30k char limit, e.g.: https://cirosantilli.com/x86-paging Or for non-programming stuff perhaps, where book form is more appropriate.

Comment: In the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration), it mentions something about _in-memory_ cache `isrMemoryCacheSize`. Shouldn't that mean that instead of storing the resulting HTML under `.next/server/pages` it is instead held in memory by default, unless that variable is set to `0`? _Note, I am using Vercel hosting, maybe the default on Vercel is file system and not in-memory?_

Comment: What happens to the cached pages after new `next buld`? Is the cache completely cleared? Asking for a product page that only makes sense to be cached for a month when the product is discontinued. But this would also mean that pages that are useful cached will have to be rebuilt, right?

Comment: @Qwerty I didn't know about `isrMemoryCacheSize`. The docs suggest there may also be a filesystem cache, it is unclear how they are partitioned when that is not 0. I think `next build` will nuke cache, but not sure. Try it out! Invalidating only certain pages: never heard of anything on CLI (which would be cool to have), but explicit API per page rebuild is in the works/available it seems (related mentions on answer).

Answer (score 12):

whenever we want to implement `ISR` or `SSG` techniques in `dynamic routes` , we are supposed to pass the paths,that we want to be statically generated at the build time,
to `getStaticPaths` function .Although , in some situations we might have *new paths* that are not  returned by `getStaticPaths` and we have to handle this paths with fallback property that is also returned from `getStaticPaths`[Next.js official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths)
.

### f**allback property can accept 3 values:**

1. **false :**
   new paths will result in a 404 page
2. **true :**
   new path will be statically generated (`getStaticProps` is called) **-** **loading state** is shown while generating page(via `router.isFallback` and showing fallback page) **-** page is rendered with required props after generating **-** new path will be cached in CDN (later requests will result in cached page) **-** crawler Bots may index fallback page (not good for Seo)
3. **"blocking" :**
   new path will be  waiting for HTML to be generated (via `SSR` )  **-**  there will be **no loading state**(no fallback page)  **-** new path will be cached in CDN (later requests will result in cached page)

**NOTE : after  Next.js 12 the `fallback:true` in `ISR` technique  wont  be showing fallback page  to crawler Bots** [Read more](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#bot-aware-isr-fallback)

Answer (score 1):

When creating dynamic pages in our app (for example a video app), we need to configure how next.js will `fallback` during the request.

If we know that the pages and our app system are quick, we are sure that our data response will be instant, we can use `fallback:blocking`. We do not need to show the loading state because Next.js will wait for this page to be fully pre-generated on the server before it serves that.

in `fallback:false` if a new page is not found 404 page will be displayed. `false` is used if you want to generate ALL of our dynamic paths during build time. In this case, in `getStaticPath` you need to fetch how many items you have in your database. Since pre-built pages are served from CDN, its look-up time is pretty quick, you are actually not fetching data, so you do not need a "loading state". You are just checking if the given URL path has a pre-generated page or not. If in the future you need to add more paths, you need to rebuild your app.

In your video app, you might have too many videos so you only prebuild the most popular video pages. If a user visits a video and its page was not pre-generated, you have to do data fetching so you need a "loading" state. Now you need to set the `fallback:true`. Since data fetching will take time, if you do not show a different component while loading, you might get like "Cannot read property "title" of undefined", since at that moment title of the video is not defined yet.

```
function Video({ videoId }) {
  const router = useRouter()   
  // If the page is getting generated  
  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }    
  // then  return the main component
}
```