# Next.js ISR ( Incremental Static Regeneration ), how to rebuild or update a specific page manually or dynamically before the interval/ISR time start?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

In NextJS Production mode -
In Incremental Static Regeneration, I have placed an auto revalidate interval to 604800 seconds(7 days). In the meantime I may need to update a specific page before the interval time start.

How can I rebuild/update a specific page without rebuilding the full site before the interval/ISR time start?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68444505/how-to-clear-delete-cache-in-nextjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is available and stable now. I have done a simple test and created a module for it. It should solve the problem you have.

[On-Demand Incremental Static Regeneration (Stable)](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-stable)

Answer (score 4):

currently next.js doesn't have a native feature for rebuilding a static page manually.

here is a [workaround](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/22384) you can refer to.

and next.js team is actively working on this topic, you can refer to this [RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11552#discussioncomment-646963)

2022/04/07 update

on-demand-isr is in beta

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-beta

Comment: Please refer to the comment above, there is out of the box functionality for this now in 12.1

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in Next.js v12.1.

I saw this feature in the 12.1 release notes, it allows a manual cache purge for a page, on demand. using the `unstable_revalidate()` function.

I haven't tested it yet though but hope this helps.

[On Demand Incremental Static Regeneration (beta)](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-1#on-demand-incremental-static-regeneration-beta)