# Show changes immediately with static site render web

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify, static-site-generation

I build a simple blog CMS with Static Site Generation web.

However, I have less trouble catching the flow.

The user creates a new blog article and I need to see the changes on the statically generated site immediately (website is on a netlify server).

I know that next, for example, provides the Incremental Static Regeneration option, but the change will not appear until the Revalidation time has elapsed and then refreshed.

Is there a way to view instant changes without waiting and refreshing on a statically generated site?

Comment: It's possible to do so with on-demand ISR, see [Next.js ISR ( Incremental Static Regeneration ), how to rebuild or update a specific page manually or dynamically before the interval/ISR time start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68062987/next-js-isr-incremental-static-regeneration-how-to-rebuild-or-update-a-spec).